# Likelihood and cross-entropy: continuous case

Tags: probability, distributions, likelihood, cross-entropy

I think it's pretty clear to me that average log-likelihood is equivalent to negative cross-entropy for discrete distributions, as shown here:

$$\frac{1}{N}\log\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \frac{1}{N}\log \prod_i q(x_i|\theta)^{Np(x_i)} = \sum_i p(x_i)\log q(x_i|\theta) = -H(p, q)$$

where $N$ is the number of samples, $q(x_i|\theta)$ is sample probability given model parameters, and $p(x_i)$ is the probability of a sample (source: wikipedia).

My question is whether a similar equivalence holds for continuous distributions?

For instance, say we have access to the data-generating continuous distribution, such that $x_i \sim p(X)$, and we have the log-likelihood function $\sum^N_i \log q(x_i | \theta)$ for $N$ data samples. Given that we know $p(X)$ and taking the limit of $N$ to infinity, could we somehow relate log-likelihood to the cross entropy integral, $\int p(x) q(x|\theta) dx$ ?

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_i \log q(x_i|\theta) = E_{p(x)}[\log q(x|\theta)]?$$

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy great point, thanks pointing it out -- all fixed.